# Is there a good way in XCode to reuse Classes across projects and easily share with other devs?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, static-libraries

I have a library that I created which I would like to use the included classes across a few different projects while maintaining the library code independently.  I would also like to be able to easily share it with other developers and have them easily implement it. **At this point it doesn't need to be a static library.**

What is the best method to do this?  I have seen other devs put their classes in a brand new `XCode` project then import that, but what is best practice?

Comment: At what point _does_ it need to be a static library?

Answer (score 2):

I think the best practice is to create a project with a static library target. Other developers can include it as a subproject in their projects.

Second best would be to simply make a directory of source files that can be included in a project on an as-needed basis. This is useful for general purpose utility code where a particular project may not want all of it.

In both cases, the library code should belong to its own git repository and included in a project as a git submodule.

If it will ever become a static library, it's best to make it one now, rather than waiting until it is "ready"; by the time you decide to switch it over, a few projects will already be using it, and converting each of them to use it will be a pain. Just do it the right way from the beginning.

If you want to distribute the library without source, you will want to use lipo to build a universal library that contains both ARM and x86 code. Unfortunately, Xcode doesn't make this as easy as it could be, but it's not too difficult with some light shell scripting.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you should create a new project and that project to any other project you want use library in. Then link the projects and you can access it. The other way which I have done also, copy the library classes directly to the new project and access the library through importing the needed classes. In my case i found creating a project and linking it with the new project is the easiest. although copying the classes isnwhat we all do when using external libraries such as cocos2d. As far as sharing it with others, just upload it to github another place of your choice so it can be used by other dev's. I hope this helps you.t

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how mature the code is, but since you specifically mention wanting to share it with other developers, you may want to investigate [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org).

Comment: Interesting option. I have heard about that, but not read much into it.

Comment: Even if you aren't ready to share the code yet, it has support for making custom Podspecs out of locally downloaded libraries.  So if you set your existing code up like a regular pod, you can then use CocoaPods to manage using it in other projects on your local machine until you're ready to share the library.